# What is a good way to know if a variable adds value to an existing regression model without its components

Tags: regression, linear-model, residuals

Suppose someone gives you the fitted values to a regression model with $k$ terms, along with the fitted coefficients. If this is all you have, and you are investigating an additional "term" or set of terms for added value, what are some good ways to quantify the value add without needing to refit the entire model?

One thing I was thinking was explaining variance in residuals. Say you use the model to generate a vector of new out of sample predictions $\hat{y}$ and then compute residuals. If you are able to explain some of the residual variance (are correlated to the residuals) then this new term $x$ could add value. Alternatively, I was considering the regression $y ~ \hat{y} + x$ and seeing how this affects the summary stats, but I'm not sure if this is telling me the right thing - are there any references on this type of analysis in practice?

Comment: There are a great many references.  In particular, some of our higher-voted posts on regression explain these concepts.  In the situation you posit you are out of luck, *because it is essential to know how the new variable is related to the old ones.* One way to make this perfectly obvious is to contemplate the case where your new variable is a linear combination of those used in the model. Although it might have excellent correlation with the residuals, *it will add absolutely no value to the model.*

Comment: @whuber, i thought regression residuals were uncorrelated to the independent variables by construction? For example, with one variable: $e^t x = (y - bx)^t x = y^tx - b x^tx = y^tx - y^tx = 0$ since $b = y^tx / x^tx$. So if you can explain variance in them then it's residual to variance accounted for already?

Comment: Of course you are correct--I was thinking of something else altogether.  What you are proposing is similar to an [added variable plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_regression_plot) (+1).

Comment: That's interesting - so what the link sounds like is "take what's left of $x_i$ after removing the projections onto the other $x$'s, and how does it correlate to the residual variance of the model which omitted $x_i$. I guess in my proposal I just don't get to do the first part here..not sure how critical that is because wouldn't colinearities of $x_i$ to the other independent variables not be present in the residuals of the original model?